# “Template parse errors: 'app' is not a known element” when an 'OK' angular2 app is built with Webpack2 and deployed

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-template, webpack-2

My angular (v2.4) application with angularfire2 is running smoothly in the development environment (express server). When I build it with "npm run build" Webpack2 builds the app and puts it into a folder named 'target'. When I run the built app from the target folder using "npm run server", the server starts up and the browser shows nothing expect the title of the app. In the console of the browser I get this error:

> "Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'app' is not a
> known element: If 'app' is an Angular component, then verify that it
> is part of this module. If 'app' is a Web Component then add
> "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
> to suppress this message."

I am providing the app's app component, index.ts, main.ts here for you. In case, if you want to see the webpack.config.js, I can provide that too.

Here is my app component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: ` 
    <app-header
      [authenticated]="auth.authenticated"
      (signOut)="signOut()"></app-header>
           
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       
     <app-footer
      [authenticated]="auth.authenticated"></app-footer>      
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  signOut(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Here is index.ts of the my app module:

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthModule } from '../auth';
import { FirebaseModule } from '../firebase';
import { HomeModule} from  '../home';


import { AppComponent } from './components/app';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './components/app-header';
import {AppFooterComponent} from './components/app-footer';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent,
    AppFooterComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], {useHash: false}),
    HttpModule,
    AuthModule,
    FirebaseModule,
    HomeModule,
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my main.ts:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// AppModule
import { AppModule } from './app';

// common styles
import './common/styles/_styles.scss';


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: sometimes I run into the same issue because of some runtime errors in my templates. please, replace your template with more simple one (for example: `<h1>testing app.component template</h1>`): if the reason is in the template, the error will gone. If it won't, we'll have to thing about other possible reasons.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15860

Comment: paste your index.html file please

Comment: Within the body of your index.html you should verify there is `<app></app>`. I normally call mine app-root instead in the AppComponent.ts selector - but what you have should suffice.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this perhaps.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407697/495157

Answer (score 1):

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthModule } from '../auth';
import { FirebaseModule } from '../firebase';
import { HomeModule} from  '../home';


import { AppComponent } from './components/app';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './components/app-header';
import {AppFooterComponent} from './components/app-footer';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent,
    AppFooterComponent
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], {useHash: false}),
    HttpModule,
    AuthModule,
    FirebaseModule,
    HomeModule,
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Add the following modification to the file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your project. I have encountered this same issue from time to time. Occasionally, I just create a fresh project and copy code over. That works 99% of the time.