# Does angular 2 Hard Coded All HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm new to Angular 2, something I'm confused about is whether Angular 2 knows all HTML tags?

I mean if in a template I have `<code></code>`, and we know that `<code>` is a valid HTML 5 element, there is nothing wrong, but if I change the element to `<codex></codex>` an exception occurs during parsing.

So does Angular 2 just knows all HTML tags? And can't I use custom tags (which are not Angular directives)?

How does the parser decide to give an error on an element?

By the way `<img>` is a valid HTML 5 element but if I use `<img></img>` some parsing exception occurs again, but if I change it to `<img/>` everything goes fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow custom tags (that aren't component selectors), you'll need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your module - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428132/custom-elements-schema-added-to-ngmodule-schemas-still-showing-error)

Comment: So how does angular detects whether an element is custom or not, does it have all element tags somewhere hard coded?

Comment: I'm not sure how it detects it, but I'd presume it recognises standard html elements and those selectors declared in all components loaded.