# Use untyped A-Frame components with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, aframe

is there a way to run a library on Angular-CLI which does not have typings?

In my case, I am trying to install [k-frame](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe) to use `aframe-template-component`and via the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation), I understand that I have to create a `typings.d.ts` file to use it with TypeScript. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript) question, I have tried the different options but I am not able to generate the file or import it directly inside the project.

I have tried also to run and install `dts-gen`, but I am getting the following error:

> Component attempted to register before AFRAME was available

Which means that I have to register A-frame first. Since I am stuck since a while, do you have an idea on how to solve the following issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: The title "Check if shader has already been registered" is confusing. You might get better responses with something like "Use untyped A-Frame components with Angular 2".

Comment: Thanks for the tip man! Appreciated. Concerning the question, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but the error `Component attempted to register before AFRAME was available` is not a TypeScript error.
It is some runtime error emitted by the library.
I see no evidence that the library exports anything at all (and there is no `"main"` property in the `package.json`). 
Also note that the example does `require('kframe');`. I would not be at all surprised I you are loading your dependencies in an invalid order.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment it's a not easy task.

I have try it with AngularCli. I have created a new project using `ng new` and I have follow this steps:

1. `ng new kframetest`
2. Install `aframe` and `aframe-template-component` using:

   ```
   npm install aframe aframe-template-component --save
   ```
3. Due to both *(zone.js and A-frame)* catch `attributeChangedCallback` you need to load A-frame before zone.js. Then *(in `polyfills.ts` file)* I have added:

   ```
   import 'aframe';
   import 'aframe-template-component';
   ```

   Just before of `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`
4. Create a simple component using [kframe sample](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template#basic-example) as template.
5. In order to Angular can parse specials html tags like `<a-entity>` you have to add a `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to `NgModule` using `schemas` property:

   ```
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
   ```
6. Run the application.

Now you can see, in the console, A-frame running:

> Put the A-Frame `script` tag in the `head` of the HTML *before* the scene to ensure everything for A-Frame is properly registered before they are used from HTML.
>
> ```
> aframe-master.js:75646 A-Frame Version: 0.5.0 (Date 10-02-2017, Commit #bf8b8f9)
> aframe-master.js:75647 three Version: ^0.83.0
> aframe-master.js:75648 WebVR Polyfill Version: dmarcos/webvr-polyfill#a02a8089b
> ```

But the big problem is that Angular tryes to parse the HTML and he don't understand the aframe template syntax, you get this errors:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token `#` at column 6 in `[src: #boxesTemplate]` in `KFrameTestComponent`
>
> ```
>  </a-assets>
>  <a-entity [ERROR ->]template="src: #boxesTemplate"
>            data-box1color="red" data-box2color="green" data-box3color"): KFrameTestComponent@10:12
> ```

> Property binding `src` not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the `@NgModule.declarations`.
>
> ```
>  </a-assets>
> ```

I have been searching about add html without Angular parse it but I didn't find ...

I have tried to add the template to the index html and it seems to work but I understand that is not your desired situation.

You can get the code from here: https://gitlab.com/jros/angularcli-kframe

Comment: Thanks for your effort man! In the end I have managed to make it work adding the template in `index.html`, even though it impacts the loading performances of the website.

Comment: I didn't know k-frame and a-frame and I liked it. Any way, have you thought about make a feature request to angular project?

Comment: The feature is about can deactivate Angular Html Parser for some elements. For example:
`<ng-avoid-angular-parser><a-elements-and-whateveryouwant/></ng-avoid-angular-parser>` this will be a good feature to admit frameworks like `k-frame`. If you decide to open a feature request let me know to up vote it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing out where to put the aframe.js script in my `index.html`. That did the trick. For your problem with the invalid tags you can add `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to your module as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428132/