# Child Component not loading after adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the app module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a component named **HostComponent** , when I put this component as a start up component everything is working and my application working fine.

Then I create one more module called AppModule and Wrap the host component inside the app component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  template: '<ds-framework-host >Loading...</ds-framework-host>'
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(){

}
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ,HostModule 
  ],
  schemas:[],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
     SomeOtherEntryComponentsHere
  ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**Index.html**

```
<body>
           <main-app></main-app>
</body>
```

**Host Module(where Host Component exist)**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    DashboardModule,
  ],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports:[]

})
export class HostModule {

 }
```

When I try to run the application I am getting the below error

[image]

To suppress this error I have added **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** to app module based on the below reference. 
[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA added to NgModule.schemas still showing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428132/custom-elements-schema-added-to-ngmodule-schemas-still-showing-error)

My error goes way but my `<ds-framework-host>` shows loading.. but nothing is executing inside this child component. In developer tools no error is showing

**Angular Version - 4.0.0.0**

How Can I resolve this error and why it's happening?

[image]

Comment: You need to import ds-framework-host component into your AppComponent . Can you also add your ds-framework-host component codes.

Comment: @junky I dentified the issue it's because I missed exports in my host module

Answer (score 0):

you don't have your ds-framework-host component in your declarations array in your app.module. You should only use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA if ds-framework-host is a native custom element

Comment: we no need to put in to declarations if the component is in another module. I have fixed my issue after I exports the component in my host module

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there wasn't enough information on what exactly is your "HostComponent". All you had to do was add HostComponent to declarations in your AppModule to use  in AppComponent.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    SomeOtherEntryComponentsHere
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by exports **HostComponent** in host module. Because this component is another module in order to use in App module we should export.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    DashboardModule,
  ],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports:[HostComponent]

})
export class HostModule {

 }
```