# Load external Framework with Angular-Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I developed an Angular 6 Framework. I build it and link .js in the index.html of a newly generated project from Angular-Cli.

But when I launch the server, I get the following error :

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>       'mw-panel' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'mw-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'mw-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

My HTML directive `mw-panel` is not found. I suppose that I have to declare something in app.module.ts, but I don't know how.

Do you face the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly ref to think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428132/custom-elements-schema-added-to-ngmodule-schemas-still-showing-error

Comment: You are right. Thank you @AliShahbaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have a missing module :) You need to add it to your app.module.ts

Seems to me meltwater components ! => https://assets.meltwater.io/gaf-ng-components/v5.3.7/docs/getting-started