# Can't use component in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 8 and even after searching for an hour on other questions I couldn't solve this. The solution seems to be under my nose but I can't see it. I keep getting this error:

'app-green' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-green' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-green' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

This is my app.module.ts code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './servers/server.component';
import { SubServerComponent } from './sub-server/sub-server.component';
import { GreenComponent } from './green/green.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    SubServerComponent,
    GreenComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-green',
  templateUrl: './green.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./green.component.css']
})
export class GreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in your `module.ts`, add `import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` and then `@NgModule({
  ...schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})`  -- for more info:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553713/8757883

Comment: Where are you trying to insert this component? Is it in `AppModule` or you created other modules?

Comment: Apparently Visual Studio Code got confused. A programmer friend told me to reload using Cmd+Shit+P and select Developer:reload window and the error disappeared.

Comment: I have this problem occasionally.  Terminate the dev server and restart.

Comment: I occasionally have to reload the VS Code window as well to eliminate false errors. It's annoying sometimes.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA for anything other than shallow unit testing; hiding the error is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must also import the **GreenComponent** in the **AppComponent**, what  you abviously didn't.
It is not sufficient to import the **GreenComponent** in the **AppModule** as one could believe.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GreenComponent } from './green/green.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],  

})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
}
```