# CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA error on ng build in angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Whenever I tried to build my project using

> ng build

I come up with the following error
.

> An unhandled exception occured: Named export 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' not found.
> The requested module '@angular/compiler' is a commonjs module which may not support all module.exports asnamed exports.
> Common JS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using
> import pkg from '@angular/compiler'
> const {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA}=pkg;

I found some suggestion on SO community regarding this as some of users already faced this situation but it didn't work for me.

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407697/5729812

Here is screenshot of

[image: package.json]

Any thoughts or suggestion would be very helpful.